# Cannot Start a Method In a Different Class Using a Library

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

I've just created my first library for an Android app I've built (I have code I need to reuse in the future across different apps) and I need to start a method I have in the main project from the library - however when I attempt to do so using the line:

```
com.project.sample.datasettings.UpdateActivity.success();
```

I'm getting a compiler error stating:

```
com.project.sample.UpdateActivity Cannot Be Resolved To A Type
```

SOURCE:

```
package com.project.sample.networktasklibrary;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import com.project.sample.networktasklibrary.XmlParserHandlerFinal;
import com.project.sample*;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
```

// this class performs the call to webservice in the background

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, InputStream> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STDataSettings";
    private static final String TAG_RESULT = "success";
    private static InputStream stream;

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            stream = getQueryResults("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31771876/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stream;
    }

    /*
     * Sends a query to server and gets back the parsed results in a bundle
     * urlQueryString - URL for calling the webservice
     */
    protected static synchronized InputStream getQueryResults(
            String urlQueryString) throws IOException, SAXException,
            SSLException, SocketTimeoutException, Exception {
        Bundle queryResults = new Bundle();

        HttpsURLConnection https = null;
        String uri = urlQueryString;
        URL urlo = new URL(uri);

        https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();
        https.setConnectTimeout(50000); // 20 second timeout
        https.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        try {
            https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlo.openConnection();

            if ("gzip".equals(https.getContentEncoding())) {
                stream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
            } else
                stream = https.getInputStream();

        } catch (SSLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

        }

        String queryResult = null;
        queryResults.putString(TAG_RESULT, queryResult);

        return stream;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream queryResults) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(queryResults);
        com.project.sample.datasettings.UpdateActivity.success();
    }
}
```

UPDATE ACTIVITY CODE SAMPLE:

```
public void success() {

        // to parse the response
        try {
            handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // to set method to save the ArryaLists from the parser
        setArrayList();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ConfigFinalActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact error instead of retyping it. You have at least one error in your error message. We also need to see your entire class file, not just part of it.

Comment: Is `com.project.sample.datasettings.UpdateActivity.success();` a static method and did you import `UpdateActivity`?

Comment: Did you just say that the LIBRARY is trying to call something in the MAIN application? Is it just me or does this not sound like a library... It's not going to rerun on other applications if it depends on code from your main application. The only way a library should call code in the main application is via an interface of some kind.

Comment: @Cruncher - I simply need a way for the Library and the main app to communicate - the library gets data from an XML file - I simply need to allow the primary app to use it (I'm going to add a snippet from it that contains the success() method I'm attempting to use - maybe it'll help shed some light on a solution)

Comment: Then the main app should request the library for that information, or your main app should implement some interface for the library to send the data when it's ready.

Comment: @Cruncher - can you point me towards an example of how that can be done? Or is simply a matter of adding the class via an import?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

The idea is that in your library you define some interface "CallBack" or something.

In your main application, wherever you want them to call a method you implement the interface "CallBack" and include the necessary methods to be able to handle it.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis it is not a static method and I attempted to import UpdateActivity into my library and eclipse is giving me an error stating UpdateActivity cannot be resolved

Comment: @Cruncher - public void success implements com.tracfone.straighttalk.networktasklibrary.NetworkTask() { results in syntax error on token "implements" and syntax error on token "void"

Comment: The class needs to implement the interface. Also, your instance of UpdateActivity needs to be passed into the library somehow. I didn't actually read your code, I'm giving you general design ideas. Also, the parameter that you pass into should be of type NetworkTask, not of type UpdateActivity

Comment: Anyone else have any suggestions? I vaguely understand how this can be implemented - but I'm still trying to put together a specific solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to add the library to the main project?
Right click the Project name -> Property -> Android -> Add. Then choose the library project.

Comment: Any other suggestions?